# Does Github use webdav?

Tags: github, webdav

As far as I know, there are 4 ways to set up a remote git server - over ssh, public access, gitosis and Gitolite? Not that i read them through. Just a bit skimmed on the website-http://git-scm.com/book/ca/Git-on-the-Server-Gitosis

However I don't know what category among them github falls into on my first thought.
I just guess... webdav?, because we issue 'git clone http://github.com/username/reponame.git' on command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For https:// GitHub uses *Smart HTTP Transport* which is just as efficient as ssh:// and git:// - faster than WebDAV and *much* faster than dumb (static) HTTP.

See
https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support
and
http://git-scm.com/2010/03/04/smart-http.html